# reading semi-formatted data

Tags: parsing, awk

I'm totally new to AWK, however I think this is the best way to solve my problem and a good time to learn AWK. 
I am trying to read a large data file that is created by a simulation program. The output is made to be readable by humans, so its formatting isn't very consistent. An example of the output is in this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsreH.png

I need a way to find a line like "He 2  4686A  -2.088   0.0071", by specifying the "He 2  4686A" part and get the following two numbers. The problem is the line "He 2  4686A  -2.088   0.0071" can appear anywhere in the table.
I know how to find the entry "He 2  4686A", but I don't know which of the 4 columns it's in. So I don't know how to address the values that follow it. 
A command that lets me just read the next two words, or tells me the location of the pattern once a match is found will both help.

/He 2  4686A/ finds the line

Ca A  3970A  -0.900   0.1100      He 2  4686A  -2.088   0.0071      S  3 18.67m  -0.371   0.3721      Ar 4 444.7A  -2.124   0.0066

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Start by doing an [AWK tutorial](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html) and try some things yourself first. SO is great for getting help regarding a specific programming (related) issue you're having. "Any help" is rather broad. Checkout SO's [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) to see what to ask, and what not to ask on SO. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

First step should be to bring what seems to be 4 columns of records into a 1-column format...then its easy with `awk` because you can then filter for the first 5 fields - like:

```
echo "He 2 4686A -2.088 0.0071" | \
awk '$1 == "He" && $2 == 2 && $3 == "4686A" {print $4, $5}'
```

which gives

```
-2.088 0.0071
```

So, for me, the only challenge is to transform your data to one-column format...And from the picture that look simple because it seems that the columns have a fixed length which you can count.

Assuming that your column-width is 30 characters (difficult to tell from a picture, beware of tabs) and you data is in `input_file`, then you could first "cut" the data into 4 columns and then pipe the output to another `awk`-process

```
awk '{
  print substr($0,1,30)
  print substr($0,31,30)
  print substr($0,61,30)
  print substr($0,91,30)
}' input_file | \
awk '$1 == "He" && $2 == 2 && $3 == "4686A" {print $4, $5}'
```

If you really just need the next two numbers behind an anchor then I would say the `grep`-solution from Costa is best for you, however this gives you the possibility to implement further logic...

Comment: That's true, the columns are of fixed length. Doing what you said will certainly work. I'll try it and let you know what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Sure, I just wanted to show how one can tackle such problems by splitting them up into simpler, "atomic" tasks...

Answer (score 2):

If you're not dead set on using `awk`, `grep` would be the easiest way...

`egrep -o "He 2 4686A \-?[0-9.]+ \-?[0-9.]+" output.txt`

EDIT: The above would work only if the spacing was done with a whitespace, which doesn't seem to be your case. In order to handle tabs and/or repeating whitespaces...

`egrep -o "He[ \t]+2[ \t]+4686A[ \t]+\-?[0-9.]+[ \t]+\-?[0-9.]+" output.txt`

Comment: this doesn't seem to return anything for me.

Comment: Probably cause the spacing has tabs, it's hard to tell just from an image. I just worked from the sample text line you pasted in your question. I'll update it to handle tabs...

Comment: You were correct, they were separated by repeating whitespaces. Man, this really is a beautiful solution. Thank you very much.